# Unable to match results when implementing 3D DFT

Tags: python, fft, dft

I am trying to implement a 3D DFT but I am running into some trouble. What I believe I should do is to just do 3 consecutive 1D DFTs, one in each direction. Assuming that the 1D DFT is correct, can you see what is wrong with this code:

```
def dft3d(self, real3d, img3d, nx, ny, nz, dir):

    #Transform depth
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            real = numpy.zeros(nz)
            img = numpy.zeros(nz)
            for k in range(nz):
                real[k] = real3d[i][j][k]
                img[k] = img3d[i][j][k]
            self.dft(real, img, nz, 1) #This was indented too much. It should work now.
            for k in range(nz):
                real3d[i][j][k] = real[k]
                img3d[i][j][k] = img[k]

    #Transform cols
    for k in range(nz):
        for i in range(nx):
            real = numpy.zeros(ny)
            img = numpy.zeros(ny)
            for j in range(ny):
                real[j] = real3d[i][j][k]
                img[j] = img3d[i][j][k]
            self.dft(real, img, ny, 1)
            for j in range(ny):
                real3d[i][j][k] = real[j]
                img3d[i][j][k] = img[j]

    #Transform rows
    for j in range(ny):
        for k in range(nz):
            real = numpy.zeros(nx)
            img = numpy.zeros(nx)
            for i in range(nx):
                real[i] = real3d[i][j][k]
                img[i] = img3d[i][j][k]
            self.dft(real, img, nx, 1)
            for i in range(nx):
                real3d[i][j][k] = real[i]
                img3d[i][j][k] = img[i]
```

I know there are built in versions of this in python, but I can't use those. I'm just testing my algorithm in python so I can compare results of my algorithm and the built in ones. As far as I could tell it worked fine for both 1D and 2D transforms, but once I expanded it to 3D the results no longer match. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instance of `self.dft` is indented too far.

Other than that, I see nothing wrong from the code provided.

As a side note, if you are using `numpy` as your code suggests, you can simplify your code significantly even without resorting to the built-in DFT/FFT.

For example, you can index a 3D numpy array like `data3D[i, j, k]`. You can slice by doing `data3D[:, j, k]`, `data3D[i, :, k]`, `data3D[:, :, k]`, etc., instead of assigning individual elements one at a time within a for loop.

Comment: Oh my. It had to be something silly. Thank you so much. You're the hero of the day.

Also, thanks for tips about numpy.

Comment: You can also roll numpy axes, so that you don't need to write three separate loops.